# condense multiple jquery if statements

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

there may not even be a solution to this...or it may be rather complicated (or more likely easy and right in front of me but I'm missing it.)

I have a table, with multiple cells (it has 12, but I'll use 2 for the example) and in each cell there is a `<ul>` with differing numbers of `<li>`.  Depending on how many `<li>`'s are used (Up to 10) I want to apply a different colour.

So to make things really simple for example lets say..

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <ul> <li>just a test</li> </ul> </td>
<td> <ul> <li>Another test</li> <li>and another</li> </ul> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And lets say that for a list with one item I want the colour green and for two items I want the colour red.  I could use some jquery like this for the first cell.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var count = $("a class name for the list").children("li").length
if (count == 1) {
$("a class name for the cell").addClass("a") }
else if (count == 2) {
$("a class name for the cell").addClass("b") }
etc
```

With some css classes for a, b, etc.

My problem is that in order to have the same function on the next cell, though independent as it may need to be a different colour is to repeat the whole if statement in jquery using different class/id names.   Is there a better way to streamline this, perhaps only needing one if statement...or at least fewer?

If there is a solution and it makes any difference, the actual build-up of each cell is like so (using the first cell as an example):

```
<td><div class="month"><h3>January</h3><ul><li>list stuff</li></ul></div></td>
```

Every cell uses the class month as it just contains some layout information in a CSS file.

EDIT: To contain fuller table layout.  There are three more rows in this table, all set out the same.

```
<table class=table>   
<tr>
<td><div class="month"><h3>January</h3><ul class=a><li>testing</li><li>testing</li><li>testing2</li></ul></div></td>
<td><div class="month"><h3>February</h3><ul class=b><li>testing</li></ul></div></td>
<td><div class=month><h3>March</h3><ul class=c><li>testing</li></ul></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //classes could be set on any outerscope, as global e.g
    var classes = ["a", "b"];            
    $("table").find("ul").each(function () {
        var count = $(this).find('li').length;
        if (!count) return; //return nothing is aka continue statement inside each loop          
        $(this).closest("div").addClass(classes[count - 1]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was going to write about using a switch statement, but I like your solution better.

Comment: I should probably mention I am, to put it elegantly, a complete noob when it comes to jquery... where would I put this, I tried a couple of alternative but it didn't work.

Comment: I wrote about it just for the sake of completeness, but this answer indeed wins in the case at hand.

Comment: @Umbr44 updated answer but you didn't provide enough relevant HTML markup in order to get more accurate answer. EDIT: it's hard to figure out your actual markup, one uses DIV .month but the former not

Comment: Now if you want more relevant help, please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/keqFn/1/   This jsfiddle contains the table and relevant css currently used.   Apology for the confusion, in the blank example in my opening post I tried to simplify things right down and stripped too much out.

Comment: Fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keqFn/3/ But here i'm adding class to DIV month, maybe not exactly what you are looking for but gives you the idea. EDIT: for adding class to LIs: http://jsfiddle.net/keqFn/4/

Comment: Ahh.. perfect thank you very much.  And looking at the code I can figure out how it works pretty much which will hopefully help me with similar things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could make use of a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

```
$(function() {

    switch ( $( '.list-class' ).children( 'li' ).length ) {
        case 1:
            $( '.cell-class' ).addClass( 'foo' );
            break;
        case 2:
            $( '.cell-class' ).addClass( 'bar' );
            break;
        case 3:
            $( '.cell-class' ).addClass( 'baz' );
            break;
        // ...
    }

});
```

Comment: Whilst we both agree the answer above is better in this situation, thank you for the alternative.